# You can't open the application "AppceleratorStudio" because it is not responding

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I was unable to open my AppceleratorStudio.

When I click on AppceleratorStudio icon in mac system, I am getting below message

"You can't open the application AppceleratorStudio because it is not responding."

Can any one help me out how to resolve it?

**Here is my environments:**

- Operating System           = Mac OS X 10.11
- Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
- npm Version                 = 2.11.3
- Titanium CLI Version          = 5.0.5
- Titanium Version              = 5.1.1.GA

**Error Image:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a full reinstall of studio?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay. Actually Appcelerator ide icon is already opened it is showing in task bar(Bottom), because of this it is not responding. I closed that icon and open once then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Terminal app from Applications/Utilities and running type these commands:

```
 % killall Dock                                            
 % killall Finder 
 % sudo killall launchservicesd
```

This should quit and reopen the Dock, then the Finder, then the LaunchServices Daemon. Afterwards, try opening the app again.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a case of another app “not responding” by killing a stuck/dead process.

I opened the Terminal app from Applications/Utilities. I ran

`ps uaxww | grep <name of process>`

Two or three processes appeared in the results.

I noted the process ID of each one.

After I ran

`kill <process ID>`

for each process, the app opened properly.